# Golang test of REST API dumps entire database

Tags: rest, unit-testing, go

I wrote a small web service to learn unit testing. There is one endpoint to get data with a three-letter string. My code runs fine. The right query is `http://localhost:8000/iata/thu`, with the last bit `thu` being the three-letter string. I can get the correct data with it. I can also successfully get 404 with wrong ones. Then I wrote the test. It fails and dumps the entire database.

The SQLite3 database, main.go, and main_test.go are in the same directory.

Here's main_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestIata(t *testing.T) {
    // "thu" is the three-letter code.
    // I also tried "http://localhost:8000/iata/thu"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/iata/thu", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(iata)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)
    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v want %v",
            status, http.StatusOK)
    }

    expected := `[{"airport_id":"10","name":"Thule Air Base","city":"Thule","country":"Greenland","iata":"THU","icao":"BGTL","latitude":"76.5311965942","longitude":"-68.7032012939","altitude":"251","timezone":"-4","dst":"E","tz_db":"America/Thule","type":"airport","source":"OurAirports"}]`
    if rr.Body.String() != expected {
        t.Errorf("handler returned unexpected body: got %v want %v",
            rr.Body.String(), expected)
    }
}
```

Here's main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type datum struct {
    AirportID    string `json:"airport_id,omitempty"`
    ...
}

func check(err error) {
    ...
}

// Accesses the database and gets relevant rows.
func getRows(column string, searchTerm string) *sql.Rows {

    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "airports.db")
    check(err)

    stmt := `SELECT * FROM airports WHERE ` + column + ` LIKE ? COLLATE NOCASE;`

    rows, err := db.Query(stmt, `%`+searchTerm+`%`)
    check(err)

    return rows
}

// Processes the data into a slice so it can be sent out as JSON.
func processData(rows *sql.Rows) []datum {
    data := []datum{}

    // For each row, insert data into a datum instance and then append to data slice.
    for rows.Next() {
        datum := datum{}
        rows.Scan(&datum.AirportID,
            ...)
        data = append(data, datum)
    }
    rows.Close()

    return data
}

// Uses the above code to get data from the database, process it, and send it.
func getAndSendData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, searchType string) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    searchTerm := params[searchType]

    datum := getRows(searchType, searchTerm)
    processed := processData(datum)

    if len(processed) == 0 {
        http.Error(w, "Data not found.", 404)
        return
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(processed)
}

func main() {
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/iata/{iata}", iata).Methods("GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}

func iata(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    searchType := "iata"
    getAndSendData(w, r, searchType)
}
```

Running the test gets the entire database dumped in the result:

```
=== RUN   TestIata
--- FAIL: TestIata (0.21s)
    main_test.go:46: handler returned unexpected body: got [ENTIRE DATABASE DUMPED HERE] want [CORRECT DATA HERE]
FAIL
exit status 1
```

I've looked through a lot of tutorials, such as [this](https://blog.questionable.services/article/testing-http-handlers-go/) one, which I feel is pretty clear. As far as I can tell, my test code is correct. I've also tried running main.go before doing the test. But that shouldn't matter, right?

What am I missing?

Comment: The request is not going through a proper server so the dynamic parameter is not going to be properly resolved and therefore `mux.Vars` won't return what you expect. Use `net/http/httptest` package, it contains examples on how to properly test requests.

Comment: @mkopriva That's what I used. Sorry, I just updated my question with it a second ago.

Comment: I still don't see a server in your test. Take a look at this (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server) Also note that you should extract the router setup our from the `main` function into its own, so that you can call it in the test and then pass it to `httptest.NewServer`.

Comment: ... something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/UM9t8xalDMj I haven't tested the code so it probably contains some errors but you should be able to get the gist from it.

Comment: @mkopriva Your code works perfectly. I didn't know I had to do that. So, thanks for that. But now, it still fails. The test gets the correct string but says it's not right. Probably should open another question for that. Could you make a solution so I can mark it as the correct one? Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you make the request `http://localhost:8000/iata/1%3D1%3B%20DROP%20DATABASE%20airports%3B%20--`?